# Default platform in msbuild

Tags: c#, windows, configuration, tfs, msbuild

My solution `App.sln` has specified only configuration `Debug|x86` and `Release|x86`. When building this solution in my computer, it works fine, but when building in another developer's computer, it raises an error saying that it doesn't exist configuration `Release|x64` in the solution. The problem is that I never set the platform when calling msbuild. Like this:

`msbuild.exe App.sln`

The computers have the same configuration (x86, WinXP).

How can I enforce or set the platform system-wide?

**Edit 2012-12-20:**
It isn't possible for us to change all projects to allow both platforms or even Any CPU. We only release x86 binaries (due compatibility with external libraries). The question is basically if there is a global variable setting the platform.

**Edit 2012-12-21:**
Vlad L answered the correct way to enforce the build using the platform desired. But in case someone else find the same problem, I created a new workspace in TFS and it solved the issue. Investigating it further, I discovered it was a cache error in workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `msbuild.exe /property:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64 App.sln`

2) Right mouse on Solution -> Properties -> configuration Properties -> button Configuration Manager. Set checkbox for all projects and then you can create new or change existing configuration or target platform for all projects at once (Checked in Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: We have about 450 projects and we don't have resources to do this change. Also, it will break as we will deliver only x86 applications. It works normally in every other developer's computers, so the question remains if there is a global variable setting this platform.

Comment: Problem again, we have about 110 solutions.

Comment: @Marlos so what kind of solution do you expect? Change one project manually, copy the difference and write a small program which searches for all *.csproj files and inserts this text.

Comment: I'll set your answer as accepted, but the real cause of the problem was a cache error in TFS workspace.